# How to handle conditional decision points in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I am in the process of converting a workflow I currently have, into Apache Airflow tasks.  The workflow is as follows:

```
1. Run set of tests.  
2. Check results
  - If the tests pass then move to the next set of tests.  
  - If the tests fail, log the failure information (time, reason, what test was ran) in a database.    
3. Send message out about failures.
```

Right now I have a PythonOperator task going that kicks off a callable that executes the set of tests based off information we have stored in MongoDB.

```
test_info_conn = MongoHook(conn_id='test_selector_mongo')
test_list = test_info_conn.find('test_selector_metadata', None).limit(2)

for count, current_test in enumerate(test_list):
    status_test_task = PythonOperator(
                     task_id='status_test_'+str(count),
                     python_callable=run_status_tests,
                     op_kwargs={'current_test':current_test},
                     provide_context=True,
                     dag=dag)
```

This is the point where I am not sure how to proceed. Would I chain another task that has a callable to handle the results, and how do I get the results to that next task in the chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For branching the workflow (2nd step), you can employ a [`BranchPythonOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c717d12f47c604082afc106b7a4a1f71d91f73e2/airflow/operators/python.py#L148)
- For sharing (log) information between tasks (2nd to 3rd step) Airflow has `XCOM`s ([`xcom_pull()` function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c717d12f47c604082afc106b7a4a1f71d91f73e2/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L1139))

---

References

- [Concepts/Branching](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching)
- [Concepts/XCOMs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#xcoms)